# How can I get Firefox to fire onscroll once, as Chrome does, per scroll "action.?"

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, onscroll

I've been working on getting a "float then fix" navigation bar working on most browsers without any JavaScript libraries (like JQuery).

It works on Chrome but I have a small problem in FF and it seems to be due to FF firing onscroll multiple times when you do a "scroll action" - PdDn, PdUp, up and down arrow keys, up and down arrows on scroll bar, clicking scroll bar, etc.

Chrome fires only once but FF first multiple times, how many tines depends upon the length of the web page and your current position.

Is there any way to get FF to fire only once like Chrome?

I'll put up a [test page](http://thetesting.site/showscrolling.html) which lets you look at how many times onscroll fires by logging "scroll" to the console. It should be up in about 10 minutes. I will put a link back to this question on the page.

There will be some comments at the top of the page explaining how to use it.

Does anyone have any ideas as to getting just one onscroll event when you peform  a "scrolling action?"

Comment: turning off smooth scrolling in firefox does the trick - also, in my Chrome, multiple events get fired on PgDn/PUp, Up,Down etc as well - until I turn off smooth scrolling too - chrome://flags/#enable-smooth-scrolling

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var timer = null;
function action(){
  // do stuff on scroll
}

function onscroll(e){
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(action.bind(this, e), 100);
}
```

This way, it only fires scroll events after 100ms of idle time, which may or may not be what you need. You may need to tweak the timeout delay to get the best result.